# Why use/create Drupal 7 module?

Tags: drupal

When do you actually use/create a module for Drupal 7? Because like i see it, you can pretty much use templates.

Comment: Can you imagine how your templates would look like if the functionality from all the modules you use would be handled in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a called [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Templates are, well, templates. They are supposed to deal with data presentation and layout. Producing, retrieving, storage and processing of data is not supposed to happen in a template. Cleanly separated features implemented in different modules ease maintenance, evolution and code re-use.

Answer (score 0):

To hook into the core functionality.

Comment: Yeah, but can't us use hooks in templates also?

Comment: Invoking hooks of course but not sure about creating them within a template.